# is this htacces or something else

Tags: .htaccess

I have uploaded codeigniter site here.

It runs fine at local server but after uploading i get this error.

“404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.”

Also,

Also “No input file specified. ”

uploaded it on free server as well and it runs fine there. www.ogc.isgreat.org
any idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

project is hosted on godaddy and godaddy has problem with CI project.

Here is the solution.

in your config/config.php, make these two changes.

$config['index_page'] = "index.php?";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "QUERY_STRING";

thought now i have problem with ajax calls.

Answer (score 1):

"No input file specified" is displayed when a file is not found, and PHP is running in CGI mode. Both errors indicate that the file cannot be found.

In order to make `file.php/blablabla` work, you've to enable [Path Info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo). Example using .htaccess:

```
AcceptPathInfo On
```